# Upload .docx .pdf edit and print via angular app

Tags: angular, pdf, printing, edit, docx

I'm working on an Angular application and I need to implement a feature that allows me to upload and preview both .docx and .pdf files. Additionally, I want to provide the capability to edit these documents by inserting variables and print the edited document. Are there any free solutions or libraries available to achieve this functionality in Angular?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sry I accidentaly instead of me typed users

Answer (score 0):

Adobe provides few of the features requested, you can check the link below:
https://developer.adobe.com/document-services/apis/pdf-embed/